# Proper way to wrap sprite for Z dimension

Tags: sprites, coordinates

I am using SFML, but I need to add some emulation of 3D by wrapping the sprite with a Z component. When sprites are drawed (or when objects moved?), their X and Y will change depending on Z.

My question is, which component should hold the sprite, and the wrapped x, y, z coords?

Supossing I have objects that inherit from Sprite, GameObject and Collider (and I am not yet sure about this or if I rather should have used compositio), I could have:

- A wrapper for Sprite, which could be Sprite3D. Sprite would be the holder of the coords used also for game logic and collision detection. In this case, how do I give access to base class/component(?) Collider of Sprite?
- Collider (inherited or composed?), holding x, y, z. In this case, how Collider would have access to Sprite in order to update it, by having a pointer to parent object/casted base class/Sprite? Or should the Sprite3D have a pointer to the collider and update its own x,y only when drawing?
- Wrapper for Both Collider and Sprite. I will need to do this with more drawable types, so this would force me to make other base class Graphic for Sprite. (Yes?)

  - Colliders are drawables?
- Make each entity have their own x, y, z, and update their sprites and hitboxes